# How to connect to https url through Apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I have a rest service url with https connection, how to connect to it as an endpoint using apache camel?

Answer (score 0):

For simple http link : http://camel.apache.org/http4.html

If you want to use the rest dsl : http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html

Typing on google "apache camel 'technology'" you'll certainly got more in depth answer.

Comment: Hi , My question is how to connect to https://url having SSL certificate